# Alterar campo varchar yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss para data dd/mm/yyyy no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, data, sql-server-2014

Caros, estou extraindo os dados de um log de pesquisa de satisfação, e estou tentando criar uma coluna com o formato data, para que eu possa agrupar os dias e meses em uma tabela dinâmica do Excel.

Para detalhar melhor, segue como vem o campo `varchar` com a data:

> ```
> 2018-08-27 00:00:59
> ```

Eu faço a query abaixo:

```
SELECT DATA, CONVERT(DATE,TB_EPA.DATA,121) AS DATA_AJUSTADA
FROM TB_EPA
```

A query me retorna o valor `"2018-08-27"` como data. Se eu tento usar o formato de data 103 que é o formato que eu quero converter, o SQL me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

A única forma que encontrei até o momento de deixar o formato da data como dd/mm/yyyy foi fazendo dois `Convert` na mesma query, porém o campo fica como `Varchar` e não consigo deixar como Data.
Segue a query:

```
SELECT DATA, CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATE,TB_EPA.DATA,121),103) AS DATA_AJUSTADA
FROM TB_EPA
```

Dessa forma o retorno da query é `"27/08/2018"`.
Mas o campo volta a ser VARCHAR, se tento fazer o Select com mais um Convert para que o valor seja retornado como Data:

```
SELECT DATA, CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATE,TB_EPA.DATA,121),103),103) AS DATA_AJUSTADA
FROM TB_EPA
```

A query retorna `2018-08-27`

Saberiam alguma forma de retornar esse campo como data(dd/mm/yyyy)? Pesquisei em vários lugares e não consegui encontrar nada que solucionasse meu problema.

Obrigado.

Comment: No primeiro `SELECT` já esta convertendo o `VARCHAR` para `DATE` e você diz que quer saber como retornar como `DATE`. Pode explicar melhor o resultado que você quer?

Comment: Olá Pagotti, ele está convertendo para DATE, porém o formato que quero é dd/mm/yyyy.
Mas ele não retorna dessa forma, ou ele dá erro, ou retorna como yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: O formato de saída ou é o da configuração atual da sessão que você está abrindo ou você tem que converter explicitamente como fez no segundo `SELECT`, mas se vai aplicar alguma função de data tem que fazer sobre o resultado do primeiro `SELECT`

Comment: Um DATE não tem formato, somente valores (no caso, os valores numéricos do dia, mês, ano, etc). Quando vc faz um select, esses valores são exibidos em algum formato, claro, mas isso não quer dizer que a data está naquele formato. Por exemplo, hoje é 29 de agosto de 2018. Eu posso exibi-lo como "2018-08-29", "29/08/18", "Aug, 29th 2018" etc. Os formatos são diferentes, mas o valor é o mesmo (todas essas strings representam a mesma data: o mesmo dia, mês e ano do calendário). Se vc quer a data em determinado formato, converta-a para varchar. Se quer usar a data em si, não precisa converter

Comment: Entendi.. 
Resolvi mudar a forma, para que dê certo na tabela Dinâmica, como não vou conseguir agrupar a data, por mês e ano na dinâmica devido ao campo ser texto. Vou criar coluna adicional com o mês, e outra com o Ano, assim dará certo o agrupamento.
De qualquer forma, agradeço pelos esclarecimentos..

Comment: Creio que a query abaixo pode ser o que está esperando. SELECT DATA, CAST( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TB_EPA.DATA,121) AS DATETIME) AS DATA_AJUSTADA FROM TB_EPA